# Why does the queryString value accumulate behind the url when using a history object in response in react?

Tags: reactjs, url, query-string, browser-history, class-completion

**first `History.push` screen**

[image]

[example code]

```
const { history } = this.props;
history.push({ pathname: 'workspace?task=14' });
```

**Result URL**

[image]

[example result]

```
Chrome URL => http://localhost3000/workspace?task=14
```

but ... If I send another request here...

**next use `History.push`**

[image]

[example code]

```
history.push('workspace?task=15');
```

**next use History push result URL**

[image]

[example result]

```
Chrome URL => http:// localhost3000/workspace?task=14?task=15
```

It overlaps...

No matter how hard I look, I can't find the results. Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem simply. My basic skills are too lacking. In conclusion, the query string value should not be put in the patch name, but it was solved when it was put in the key search. I think I studied a lot. I worked hard for 4 hours with just this.

**before**

```
history.push({pathname: `workspace?task=14`});
```

**after**

```
history.push({pathname: `workspace` , search: `task=14`})
```